# How to use ITestResult for extend reports in JUnit Maven in @after

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, report, extend

I am trying to capture screenshots in my extent report by using JUnit Maven.

I am able to generate the reports but ITestResult is not working in JUnit Maven in @After.  I would highly appreciate if somebody can help in the code replacement from TestNG to Junit. Please find attached my code.

```
@After public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException {

    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE){
        String temp = Utility.getScreenshot(driver);
        logger.fail(result.getThrowable().getMessage(), MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(temp).build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using JUnit 5.

You will have to implement your own test execution listener based on the interface `TestExecutionListener`.

The following method will be called after any test execution:

```
default void executionFinished​(TestIdentifier testIdentifier,
                               TestExecutionResult testExecutionResult){

  if(testExecutionResult.getStatus() == TestExecutionResult.Status.FAILED){
    // your code here
  }
}
```